# Missing roles claim in jwt token issued by AAD for native app

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, access-token, adal

I have a native function app which is requesting for a JWT token from AAD. I can't see roles claim in JWT token issued by AAD. Is there some configuration I am  missing which is required for roles claim?

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign roles for users/groups via the Portal for native apps AFAIK.
Did you assign them via the Graph API?

I assume roles are not supported in native apps since they run on a user's device (just my guess for their reasoning).
What you can do is setup user roles on your back-end API app registration and check user roles from the access token within your native app.